# How to make a function "wait for" an object before being defined?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the "Previous" button, which calls the toPrevious() function, it gives me an error saying picker (which toPrevious() reads) isn't defined, because picker is created after DOMContentLoaded. If I put toPrevious() inside of DOMContentLoaded, it says toPrevious() is not defined, because toPrevious() hasn't been defined when the button is clicked

How do I make toPrevious() be called only after DOMContentLoaded (and picker) is defined, but not cause any issues with the button?

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Assignment 3</title>
  <link href="picker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Picker.js"></script>

  <script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const picker = new Picker(document);

    function toPrevious() {
      console.log("hi");
      picker.toPrev(document);
    }

});

  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="d0">{{H1}}</th>
      <th id="d1">{{H2}}</th>
      <th id="d2">{{H3}}</th>
      <th id="d3">{{H1}}</th>
      <th id="d4">{{H2}}</th>
      <th id="d5">{{H3}}</th>
      <th id="d6">{{H3}}</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="prev" onclick="toPrevious()"> Previous</button>
  <button id="next" onclick="toNext()">Next</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
class Picker {
  /**
   * Create a date picker
   * @param {string} containerId id of a node the Picker will be a child of
   */ 

  constructor(containerId) {

    console.log(containerId.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML);
    }

  toPrev(document) {
    console.log(document);
  }
```

Comment: I don't know much about JS, but I think your problem is likely due to attempting to listen to `DOMContentLoaded`. Instead try defining a simple function and using `<body onload="myInitFunction()">` to call it.

Comment: you have a scoping issue, you've declared `toPrevious()` inside a function `() => {}` so it's only available within that function

Comment: a) move the `toPrevious` function declaration and the `let picker;` outside of the `DOMContentLoaded` callback into the global scope b) attach the `onclick` listeners from inside the `DOMContentLoaded` listeners to the `document.getElementById('prev')` element, because `toPrevious` is only in scope there

Comment: @Locke No, using `DOMContentLoaded` is totally fine.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, what do you mean by "attach the onclick listeners from inside the DOMContentLoaded listeners to the document.getElementById('prev') element"?

Comment: Remove the `onclick="toPrevious()"`  attribute from the HTML, which requires a `toPrevious` function in the global scope, and instead write `document.getElementById('prev').onClick = toPrevious;` in your code, where the function is declared. (Or even better, `document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', toPrevious);`).